# Winapi: Security descriptor with size SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH has ACL

Tags: winapi, acl, msdn, dacl

I'm new with winapi and I came across with this code:

```
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SD = NULL;

Int length = SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH;

SD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, length);

if (SD == NULL)
{
  printf("Error! SD is null.\n");
}

if (InitializeSecurityDescriptor(SD, 
                                   SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION) == FALSE)
{
  printf("Error in InitializeSecurityDescriptor.\n");
}

if (SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(SD, TRUE, acl, FALSE) == FALSE)
{
  printf("Error in SetSecurityDescriptorDacl.\n");
}
```

MSDN website shows me that `The minimum length of a security descriptor is SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH. A security descriptor of this length has no associated security identifiers (SIDs) or access control lists (ACLs).` But As I tested this code it worked fine. I did little research and found MSDN  [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595(v=vs.85).aspx) about security descriptors, and code like this is used there too. I think I misunderstood something, Shouldn't using `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH` and then adding ACL cause error? Sorry if question sound silly.

Comment: You are using an absolute security descriptor, so the DACL is not stored in the `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` structure. Yes, this is confusing. There are two types of security descriptors (relative and absolute). Relative security descriptors are self-contained and must hold everything they reference. Absolute ones contain references to external data.

Comment: Thank you very for your reply and sorry for late response. Does it mean that In my case `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH` length is completly enough?

Comment: The code is correct as is. Note that you must not modify or free `acl` because `SD` is using it. You cannot modify or free `acl` until you free `SD`.